# How to setup tresholds to spot keywords from a list in pocketsphinx-android?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I would like my Android application to do continuous keywords spotting.
I'm modifying the pocketsphinx android demo to test how I can do it.
I wrote this list in a file named en-keywords.txt picking words from *cmudict-en-us.dict*:

```
rainbow /1e-50/
about /1e-50/
blood /1e-50/
energies /1e-50/
```

In setupRecognizer method I removed every search and added to the recognizer only this keyword search:

```
File keywords= new File(assetsDir, "en-keywords.txt");
        recognizer.addKeywordSearch(KWS_SEARCH, keywords);
```

Finally I modified onPartialResult like this:

```
public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
        if (hypothesis == null)
            return;

        String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();

        switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
    }
```

so that every time a partial result is found with a not null hypotesis the onResult is called and the search starts again.

What I see in the app running is not what I'm expecting:

1. onPartialResult has a not null hypotesis every time I speak also if I say something very different from what I'm looking for;
2. also if I say "hey" onPartialResult hypotesis is often composed by more than one word; worst case I say "hey" and the method understand "rainbow about energies blood"
3. onResult method is then called but it prints a Toast with a text different from the last found by onPartialResult; like if it was a concat of strings done in some not trivial order.

I tried with different tresholds for keywords but I didn't find my way... Probably I'm missing some basic concept or some configuration parameter...
Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Ok, I find out this on the [https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/05d09693/?limit=25] sourceforge forum: the higher the treshold (max 1) the less false alarm (with the risk of missing true matches) and viceversa (min 1e-45). I'll try to work on tresholds...

Comment: I find out also that a low treshold can bring to more than one possible match [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412843/split-hypothesis-on-individual-keyphrases). However when I have more than one match in my hypotesis `recognizer.getDecoder().seg()` seems to be always empty... is that normal?

Comment: I would recommend to read the docs http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm#keyword_lists

Comment: Thanks @Nikolay, I already did. So I think you confirm the solution to my question is to tune tresholds. Can you tell me something about having an hypotesis with more than one match and an empty `recognizer.getDecoder().seg()`?

Comment: It is also helpful to follow the tutorial recommendations. To get help on detection threshold you need to provide the test data used for tuning as described in tutorial linked above.

Comment: Yes sure @Nikolay thanks, I'm tuning it with a fast test to start and then I will tune with a longer audio record. When I try to iterate over  `recognizer.getDecoder().seg()` no iteration is done: do you have any hint about it?

Comment: You can ask separate question about this and provide the data to reproduce your problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely the solution is to understand how thresholds work and to tune them correctly. I read from [sourceforgeforum](https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/05d09693/?limit=25]) that the higher the treshold (max 1) the less false alarm (with the risk of missing true matches) and viceversa (min 1e-50).
Pocketsphinx code will use your threshold and return a match if the weight of a possible recognition is greater or equal to your threshold: giving a keyphrase a threshold of 1 means you want to have that keyphrase in the result only if pocketsphinx is absolutely sure of what has been spoken.

**I was using 1e-50 which is a very low treshold that leads to a lot of false alarms: with that treshold almost everything you say will be understood as one or more of the keywords in your list.** This is the answer to points 1 and 2 in my question.

About my 3rd point the answer is that **`hypothesis.getHypstr()` in onResult contains a concat of every possible match found**. To discern from one match to another by looking at weights it should be possible to iterate over Segments: `recognizer.getDecoder().seg()` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412843/split-hypothesis-on-individual-keyphrases)).

This is not ended up anyway. To implement a well performing recognizer one has to follow some rules in choosing keyphrases and then to perform treshold tuning. Like the [CMU tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm#keyword_lists) said:

1. For the best accuracy it is better to have keyphrase with 3-4 syllables;
2. Too short phrases are easily confused.

Comment: From my little experience I would add for keyphrases selection:
 1. use single keywords instead of keyphrases;
 2. use a limited list so you will have little similarity between keywords.

Comment: what do you think about that @Nikolay?