# Android PocketSphinx : How to reset hypothesis.Hypstr()?

Tags: android, android-service, voice-recognition, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I want my device to continuously listen for a keyword. I am using PocketSphinx for this purpose.I found a demo project on github which makes PocketSphinx to continuously listen using Service.

Here is the [link to github project](https://github.com/ihrupin/SpeechRecognitionService)

It works fine for the first time but after that hypothesis.Hypstr() returns the same string again and again.

I want to clear the string inside the hypothesis.Hypstr() to make this app works fine for me.

Here is my Service class:

```
package com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.IBinder;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Assets;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Hypothesis;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.RecognitionListener;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizer;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizerSetup;

/**
 * Created by Igor Khrupin www.hrupin.com on 6/3/16.
*/
public class VoiceService extends Service implements
    RecognitionListener {

private static final String LOG_TAG = VoiceService.class.getSimpleName();


/* Named searches allow to quickly reconfigure the decoder */
private static final String KWS_SEARCH = "wakeup";

/* Keyword we are looking for to activate menu */
private static final String KEYPHRASE = "hello";

private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    // Check if user has given permission to record audio
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
    if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        runRecognizerSetup();
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private void runRecognizerSetup() {
    // Recognizer initialization is a time-consuming and it involves IO,
    // so we execute it in async task
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
        @Override
        protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Assets assets = new Assets(VoiceService.this);
                File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
                setupRecognizer(assetDir);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return e;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
            if (result != null) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Failed to init recognizer ");
            } else {
                switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (recognizer != null) {
        recognizer.cancel();
        recognizer.shutdown();
    }
}

/**
 * In partial result we get quick updates about current hypothesis. In
 * keyword spotting mode we can react here, in other modes we need to wait
 * for final result in onResult.
 */
@Override
public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    if (hypothesis == null)
        return;

    String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
    if (text.contains(KEYPHRASE)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onPartialResult text=" + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
    }

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPartialResult text=" +text);
}

/**
 * This callback is called when we stop the recognizer.
 */
@Override
public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    if (hypothesis != null) {
        String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onResult text=" +text);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
}

/**
 * We stop recognizer here to get a final result
 */
@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    if (!recognizer.getSearchName().contains(KWS_SEARCH))
        switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEndOfSpeech");
}

private void switchSearch(String searchName) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "switchSearch searchName = " + searchName);
    recognizer.cancel();
    recognizer.stop();
    // If we are not spotting, start listening with timeout (10000 ms or 10 seconds).
    recognizer.startListening(searchName, 10000);
}

private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) throws IOException {
    // The recognizer can be configured to perform multiple searches
    // of different kind and switch between them

    recognizer = SpeechRecognizerSetup.defaultSetup()
            .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
            .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))

            .setRawLogDir(assetsDir) // To disable logging of raw audio comment out this call (takes a lot of space on the device)
            .setKeywordThreshold(1e-45f) // Threshold to tune for keyphrase to balance between false alarms and misses
            .setBoolean("-allphone_ci", true)  // Use context-independent phonetic search, context-dependent is too slow for mobile


            .getRecognizer();
    recognizer.addListener(this);

    /** In your application you might not need to add all those searches.
     * They are added here for demonstration. You can leave just one.
     */

    // Create keyword-activation search.
    recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);
}

@Override
public void onError(Exception error) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onError " + error.getMessage());
}

@Override
public void onTimeout() {
    switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onTimeout");
}
```

}

and Logcat after starting the service in case anyone needs:

> 02-17 14:27:51.563 10121-10121/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/VoiceService: switchSearch searchName = wakeup
>   02-17 14:27:52.115 10121-10121/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/SpeechRecognizer: Cancel recognition
>   02-17 14:27:52.115 10121-10121/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/SpeechRecognizer: Start recognition "wakeup"
>   02-17 14:27:52.116 10121-10121/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/VoiceService: onPartialResult text=hello hello
>   02-17 14:27:52.119 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice D/SpeechRecognizer: Starting decoding
>   02-17 14:27:52.119 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: INFO: pocketsphinx.c(1006): Writing raw audio log file: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice/files/sync/000000256.raw
>   02-17 14:27:52.930 10121-10139/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice V/ViewRootImpl: Resizing android.view.ViewRootImpl@3b6eb36: frame=[222,1596][857,1728] contentInsets=[0,0][0,0] visibleInsets=[0,0][0,0] reportDraw=true
>   02-17 14:27:52.937 10121-10135/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/libGameXtend: LUCID_1 (1487321872937) GameXtend is currently running in Manual mode
>   02-17 14:27:52.937 10121-10135/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/libGameXtend: LUCID_1 (1487321872937) GameXtend is currently running in no_save Save power state. 
>   02-17 14:27:52.937 10121-10135/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/libGameXtend: LUCID_1 (1487321872937) com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice is currently running with GameXtend, with PS parameter = 1. , ICE is not supported. PS parameter source is PowerXtend configuration
>   02-17 14:27:52.937 10121-10135/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/libGameXtend: LUCID_1 (1487321872937) PowerXtend touch feature is not active
>   02-17 14:27:53.016 10121-10121/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/VoiceService: onBeginningOfSpeech
>   02-17 14:27:53.020 10121-10121/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/VoiceService: switchSearch searchName = wakeup
>   02-17 14:27:53.604 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: INFO: cmn_prior.c(131): cmn_prior_update: from < 
>   02-17 14:27:53.604 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: 11.77 
>   02-17 14:27:53.604 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -12.91 
>   02-17 14:27:53.604 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -4.04 
>   02-17 14:27:53.604 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -3.12 
>   02-17 14:27:53.604 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  1.62 
>   02-17 14:27:53.604 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -0.05 
>   02-17 14:27:53.604 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  2.21 
>   02-17 14:27:53.604 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  1.17 
>   02-17 14:27:53.604 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -0.68 
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  3.51 
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  0.98 
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  1.02 
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  0.26 
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: >
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: INFO: cmn_prior.c(149): cmn_prior_update: to   < 
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: 10.72 
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -11.73 
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -3.15 
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -1.51 
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  2.40 
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -0.52 
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  2.35 
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  0.37 
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -1.32 
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  1.89 
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  0.47 
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -0.15 
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -0.24 
>   02-17 14:27:53.605 10121-18269/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: >
>   02-17 14:27:53.615 10121-10121/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/SpeechRecognizer: Cancel recognition
>   02-17 14:27:53.615 10121-10121/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/SpeechRecognizer: Start recognition "wakeup"
>   02-17 14:27:53.616 10121-10121/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/VoiceService: onPartialResult text=hello
>   02-17 14:27:53.620 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice D/SpeechRecognizer: Starting decoding
>   02-17 14:27:53.620 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: INFO: pocketsphinx.c(1006): Writing raw audio log file: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice/files/sync/000000257.raw
>   02-17 14:27:54.464 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: INFO: cmn_prior.c(99): cmn_prior_update: from < 
>   02-17 14:27:54.464 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: 10.72 
>   02-17 14:27:54.464 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -11.73 
>   02-17 14:27:54.464 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -3.15 
>   02-17 14:27:54.464 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -1.51 
>   02-17 14:27:54.464 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  2.40 
>   02-17 14:27:54.464 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -0.52 
>   02-17 14:27:54.464 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  2.35 
>   02-17 14:27:54.464 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  0.37 
>   02-17 14:27:54.464 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -1.32 
>   02-17 14:27:54.464 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  1.89 
>   02-17 14:27:54.464 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  0.47 
>   02-17 14:27:54.464 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -0.15 
>   02-17 14:27:54.464 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -0.24 
>   02-17 14:27:54.464 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: >
>   02-17 14:27:54.464 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: INFO: cmn_prior.c(116): cmn_prior_update: to   < 
>   02-17 14:27:54.464 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: 11.32 
>   02-17 14:27:54.465 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -11.36 
>   02-17 14:27:54.465 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -2.11 
>   02-17 14:27:54.465 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -0.38 
>   02-17 14:27:54.465 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  3.04 
>   02-17 14:27:54.465 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -0.80 
>   02-17 14:27:54.465 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  1.81 
>   02-17 14:27:54.465 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  0.35 
>   02-17 14:27:54.465 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -2.00 
>   02-17 14:27:54.465 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  1.64 
>   02-17 14:27:54.465 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  0.81 
>   02-17 14:27:54.465 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx:  0.11 
>   02-17 14:27:54.465 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: -0.10 
>   02-17 14:27:54.465 10121-18294/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/cmusphinx: >
>   02-17 14:27:54.496 10121-10121/com.hrupin.speechrecognitionservice I/VoiceService: onBeginningOfSpeech

**NOTE** : I want to reset the hypothesis.getHypstr() string so my program will work fine for the next time.

I think this is sufficient to explain but if i miss anything please let me know in the comment.

Thankyou.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup tresholds to spot keywords from a list in pocketsphinx-android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522815/how-to-setup-tresholds-to-spot-keywords-from-a-list-in-pocketsphinx-android)

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Setting threshold will help me to get exact keyword without any confusion. But what after that, hypothesis.Hypstr() will return the same string over and over.My question is how can i reset this string to null so program will work fine for next time.

Comment: Hypothesis is already reset in your code in switchSearch. recognizer.cancel() does that. Your only problem is too many false alarms.