# Unable to iterate over SegmentList while more than one match is found

Tags: android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I'm modifying the pocketsphinx android demo to test continuous keywords spotting based on a keywords list and relative thresholds.

When the onResult method of my implementation of edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.RecognitionListener is called this string
`hypothesis.getHypstr()` will contain the list of possible matches.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412843/split-hypothesis-on-individual-keyphrases) that to get every single match and their weights it is possible to do like this:

```
for (Segment seg : recognizer.getDecoder().seg()) {
    System.out.println(seg.getWord() + " " + seg.getProb());
}
```

**However my code running is never iterating over segments like if SegmentList was empty while `hypothesis.getHypstr()` shows more than one match.**

To reproduce the case I'm using this keyword list with very low tresholds so that more matches are easily found:

```
rainbow /1e-50/
about /1e-50/
blood /1e-50/
energies /1e-50/
```

My `onPartialResult` method is doing nothing while:

```
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
}

public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    if (hypothesis != null) {

    for (Segment seg : recognizer.getDecoder().seg()) {
        //No iteration is done here!!!
        Log.d("onResult", seg.getWord() + " " + seg.getProb());
    }

        String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
        makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

For example if I say "energies" then `hypothesis.getHypstr()`="blood about energies blood" but no iteration is done over SegmentList: I can see it by putting a breakpoint at the beginning of the onResult method.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Most likely it iterates, but prints nothing. You also need to move the loop inside hypothesis != null condition.

Comment: Thanks @Nikolay, I'm not looking to the output in standard output but instead I'm debugging the code and the block is never entered. You are right I will move the hypothesis != null condition, but anyway while debugging I can see the hypothesis is not null because the following block is entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a threading issue here. `onResult` message is delivered when recognizer is already restarted in `switchSearch` and so hypothesis is cleared and query for result returns nothing.

You can put this code inside `switchSearch` before recognizer is restarted, then it will work ok:

```
private void switchSearch(String searchName) {
    boolean wasRunning = recognizer.stop();

    if (wasRunning) {
        for (Segment seg : recognizer.getDecoder().seg()) {
            Log.d("!!!! ", seg.getWord());
        }
    }

    // If we are not spotting, start listening with timeout (10000 ms or 10 seconds).
    if (searchName.equals(KWS_SEARCH))
        recognizer.startListening(searchName);
    else
        recognizer.startListening(searchName, 10000);

    String caption = getResources().getString(captions.get(searchName));
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text)).setText(caption);
}
```

If you use only keyword spotting, you can also put this code inside onPartialResult which is invoked as soon as keyphrase is detected, not when silence is detected. That makes reaction faster. You do not need onEndOfSpeech and onResult in pure keyword spotting.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, it was the threading issue you pinpoint. Now I'm using only onPartialResult and stopping and restarting the recognizer at the end of that. Do you see any drawback? I see probabilities are negative values (something like -2340), is the most probable match the one nearest to 0?

Comment: I'm stopping and restarting the recognizer so that hypotesis and SegmentList is cleaned every time. Is there a better way? Sometimes is happens to say a keyphrase that is apparently not caught in onPartialResult but instead it is showed up after the next speech also if something very different was said